# PHP using preg_match to get title from article

Tags: php, regex

I am having a strange problem with preg_match. I am using a regular expression that grabs the title of an article, basically looks for the  tag:

```
preg_match('#(\<title.*?\>)(\n*\r*.+\n*\r*)(\<\/title.*?\>)#', $data, $matches)
```

When I print out the $matches array I get nothing. But when I try the same thing in a regular expression tester, it works fine. I have even tried putting in a string that would definitely match it in place of the $data variable, without any luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you trying to match <title></title> tags or something from an XML file.. Can you be more specific and provide some examples of the string you're trying to match please :)

Comment: Thou shalt not use regular expressions to parse HTML or XML structures

Comment: Thou shalt use PHP's native DOM functions instead: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: The data being passed in is any articel. Right now I am testing just some cnn article that I get using CURL. I put that page into a variable and attempt the preg match on it. I know it is pulling in the article correctly because I can echo out that article. 

But even if I try:

preg_match('#(\<title.*?\>)(\n*\r*.+\n*\r*)(\<\/title.*?\>)#', '<title>This is a title</title>', $matches);

and try a simple title string for the preg match then it still gives me no results.

Comment: If using PHP's native DOM functions faileth, thou shalt seek shelter with the [Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), which forgives the sins of broken HTML more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to backslash-quote your backslashes.

PHP's string parser removes one layer of backslashes, and then the regular-expression engine consumes another layer, so (for example) recognizing a backslash requires FOUR of them in the source code.

Beyond that, you might try taking advantage of the XML recognition stuff in PHP, or do less clever string handling. Usually when REGEXes break, it's because you're trying to be too clever with them. Consider looking only for the " and remove the whole title tag, and then strip whitespace out of the string, and VOILA! A title.

See also http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Answer (score 6):

If you still want to use `regex` and not `DOM`, here's what you can do:

```
if(preg_match("/<title>(.+)<\/title>/i", $data, $matches))
     print "The title is: $matches[1]";
else
     print "The page doesn't have a title tag";
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Guess I was just making it too complicated. ALthough not sure why it would work in the tester and not in the actuall script.

Comment: @pfunc, I did this (quick and dirty) and it works very fine and shows the title of the page. I guess you have to use `echo $matches[2];` to make it work.
     $data = file_get_contents("http://localhost/");
     preg_match('#(\<title.*?\>)(\n*\r*.+\n*\r*)(\<\/title.*?\>)#', $data, $matches);
     echo $matches[2];

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use, you know, an HTML parser for HTML:

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($HTML);

echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: I prefer to use SimpleHTMLDOM extention myself, but this method doesn't require an external library.

Comment: yes, but DOMDocument is pretty strict in regards to markup validity. It won't work on many pages.

Comment: supress errors when you use `->loadHTML()` and you'd be surprised how well it will handle mangled HTML

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
preg_match("/<title>(.*)<\/title>/is", $html, $matches);
```

From this source:
https://gist.github.com/jeremiahlee/785770

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (preg_match('%(<title.*?\b(?!\w))(\n*\r*.+\n*\r*)(\b(?=\w)/title.*?\b(?!\w))%', $data, $matches)) {
    $title = $matches[1];
} else {
    $title = "";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Like everyone else, this has the "use a parser, not regex" disclaimer.  However, if you still want regex, look at this:

```
$string = "<title>I am a title</title>";
$regex = "!(<title[^>]*>)(.*)(</title>)!i";
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);

//should output:
array(
    [1] => "<title>"
    [2] => "I am a title"
    [3] => "</title>"
)
```